# App Launch noticeably slow on simulator.

Tags: ios, debugging, instruments

I am running an app on the simulator and the launch screen is shown for much longer than normal, and then oddly fades into the app with what seems to be an opacity animation.  I commented out all functions up until the viewDidLoad in the initial view controller and this didn't help.  I placed log statements at points that might be slowing down or delaying but all the logs are logged out immediately and then this delay goes on for a few seconds and the fade happens.  I tried using time profiler in instruments but the read-outs from completely mysterious to me.

Is this familiar to any one or are there other steps I can take to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you accidentally turned on Slow Animations in the simulator. Just turn it off again (Debug > Slow Animations, Command-T).